# Google Maps Javascript API key

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps JavaScript API, and have obtained an API key for my registered project on the Google site.

I am at a point in my development where I would like to deploy the app to others as well, for more extensive testing.

The API key that I have was obtained by creating a project on googles interface, and also by providing my own work email address. I left the key open without any restrictions.

Can others in my organisation also use this API key to connect to the maps?

What do I do in terms of deployment to production systems, in terms of the key I will use there? We have quite a lot of clients, and I would like detailed information such as how many connections google will allow for this key etc.

Comment: On the Google Maps page where you created the key it is stated that the reason for restricting your key is to avoid the key being stolen and used by others. Hence,  as long as it is not restricted any other person can use your key. Members of your organisation can also use it even if it is restricted as long as it is used on the domain defined when creating the restriction.

Comment: Google Maps also stated that your key can be called 25 000 times per 24 hours for free. Money comes in only when it exceeds that number. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limitation will be applied at the level of your Google account. So It doesn't matter how much clients you have or how much coworkers use it the limitations are global.

You can check these limitations on real time on google console: https://console.developers.google.com/.

The default limits (free API key) are:

- 25 000 maps loading each 24 hours
- 50 request per second

It's important to use API key restriction, try applying a DNS restriction if you have only one DNS, but your co-workers or you won't be able to use it if you don't use the DNS.

I'll recommend you to have two API keys one of your clients and one for your coworkers, so you just applied the API key restrictions to your clients. It will also be easier to check usage onto the clients only. The limitation is on your account not your API key anyway.

Comment: Yes this is the gate to explore all function provided by google